# Paragraphs comparison C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I have same problem on doing a text comparison program.

I used vector to store my string array since we don't know the length of the paragraphs.
I created words and words1 for inputting  2 paragraphs from 2 txt. files.
words is for the original one as the reference.
words1 is the user input, the one we need to compare it to the original one to check how many mistakes the user did.

```
while (fin1 >> str) 
    {                  
        words1.push_back(str);
    }
    fin.close();
```

Then I used a for loop to do the comparison.

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (words.at(i) != words1.at(i))
            count++;
    }
```

But, the problem is that if the length of two paragraphs is different, it will returns me a error since the words.size() is different.

For examples, 
The original txt(words) : Today is Wednesday, I'm so happy to talk to you guys.
The one input by users(words1) : Today is ***Tuesday***, I'm so happy to ***tell*** to you guys.

This is fine, my program can show me the number of mistakes is 2.
But if there is any missing words or some extra words. The program will just crush.

Examples:
The original txt : 
Today is Wednesday, I'm so happy to talk to you guys.

The one input by users : 
Today is Tuesday, I'm to talk to you guys.

Tuesday doesn't match Wednesday and 'happy' and 'to' are missing
So it should be count as 3 errors.

Or

The one input by users :
Today is Tuesday, I'm so happy to ***to to*** talk to you guys.

Tuesday doesn't match Wednesday and two extra 'to'. 
So it should be counted as 3 errors.

I'm not sure if there is a way to count this kind of errors

So the easiest way to solve the problem is just to add some dummy into the shorter array to make sure their length as the same?

Hope somebody can discuss with me:) Thank you!

Comment: Find the size of each string, and see which one is smaller or equal to, and only go up to that amount in your for loop.

Comment: Do u mean by the size of each single words? if u mean the size of the whole array, i think i cannot use the smaller one since if the user input is less than the original one. Those missing words should count as mistakes

Comment: @Starf15h..having some confusion in how you are taking inputs and what you want to compare..please mention it..

Comment: I don't understand. If you are reading from a file or getting user input it is all being stored in the vector. Those vectors get filled at one point in the program. When they are filled just find the size of each VECTOR and when comparing the VECTOR's, have your for-loop or whatever loop go up to the smallest SIZE of the two vectors.

Comment: @RDX I'm sorry that my expression is bad. I just taking input by ifstream from two text files. And one is the reference the other one is typed by the users. I want to check how many mistakes the user made compare to the original text.

Comment: @Omid CompSCI For example: if the vector1 stored : "I have a pen" the size of the vector is 4. And the vector2 stored : "I have a blue pen" the size of the vector2 is 5. If i just go up to the 4. how many mistakes do u think it will shows?

Comment: Consider [std::lexicographical_compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare)

Comment: Lets say first sentence is: "Hello World" Second sentence is: "Hell" your loop would only go up to 4 which is the size of the 2nd sentence. Now you can compare the loop up to 4 characters, you see that in this case all 4 match. So you know 4 is correct. Now since the user didn't type anything else in the second sentence you just find the rest by doing First sentence size - 2nd sentence size + (Number you found correct which is 4 in this case)

Comment: "Hello World" = 10 characters, "Hell" = 4 characters, Loop up to only 4, H matches H, e matches e, l matches l, l matches l. Then you stop your counter should be 4 right now. Then take size of bigger vector which is "Hello World" = 10 characters subtract by second vector which is "Hello" 4 characters, 10 - 4 = 6 characters weren't entered. But he got 4 correct, so you just output 4.

Comment: Or if you want to say how many were wrong, your counter would only increment when wrong, so in the case above your counter would be 0, because Hell is matching with Hell in Hello World. However you can use the first sentence size - second sentence size and get 10 - 4= 6 remaining that user didn't enter therefore he got 6 wrong.

Comment: @Starf15h for your example, "I have a pen" is 12 characters, and "I have a blue pen" is 17 characters. Your loop goes up to 12, and there for compares "I have a pen" with  "I have a blu" your counter would be 3 because p != b, e != l, n != u. Now you take the highest size of sentence which is 17 characters and subtract it from your smaller sentence size which is 12 characters. ( 17 - 12) = 5. You now say 5 + your total you found incorrect which was 3 ( 5+ 3) = 8 incorrect.

Comment: How do you want to count mistakes? This seems far from trivial, especially for complex mistakes (e.g. writing one word as two words like blackberry being written black berry)

Comment: @Omid CompSCI while (fin1 >> str).  ">>" ,I guess the data will stores as string instead of one character. But, the point is that I want to know if there is any problem to count the 'missing words' or 'extra words'. Because it your case. "I have a blue pen" and "i have a pen" it will count as two mistake since 'blue' doesn't match the 'pen' and 'pen' doesn't match with the space.

Comment: @Rerito Yes, this is what i'm considering. In my code. 'black' doesn't match with 'blackberry', so 1 mistake and 'berry' is an extra word. But if i just count all the words after extra/missing word as mistake, is this a good way to solve the problem? I mean "A B C D E" compare to  "A C D E". B is missing, Obviously, it's just one mistake because B is missing. But, I have no idea how to tell the computer to judge this. So i can only compare A to A, B to C, C to D, D to E and E to nothing. so there is 4 mistakes in the above case.

Comment: @Starf15h That's the problem. I just pointed it out. If I had an answer I would be writing it now but unfortunately I don't! :(

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I'm sorry that I couldn't understand how to use it after seeing the examples and output :'(

Comment: @Starf15h: Then spend more time learning programming (read http://norvig.com/21-days.html ...) and C++ (read  http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/ ...). Also read wikipage on [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

Answer (score 0):

Determine which vector has less entries, e.g. `const size_t compare_length = std::min( words.size(), words1.size());` Then compare up to `compare_length` only. (using C++ 11: `const auto compare_length = std::min( words.size(), words1.size());`)

Comment: If i only compare up to a shorter one. How many mistake should count with 'A B C D E' to 'A B  D E '

Comment: well, A and B match, C/D and D/E don't, then it stops. 2 matches, 2 errors.

Comment: how about the E and the empty part. should it be count as 3 errors?

Comment: Well, it's a mismatch between the two vectors/paragraphs, so it would make sense, yes. Add the length difference of the two vectors to the number of errors.